# Electric field due to a uniformly charged plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

I have a plane that aligned on the $x$-$y$ plane extending from $x=-a$ to $x=+a$ and $y=-b$ to $y=+b$
and I want to find the electric field intensity at a point **h** along the $z$-axis.

$\sigma \equiv $ **area charge density**

The final answer is :

$$\vec E= \frac{\sigma}{\pi \epsilon_o} \tan^{-1}({\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+h^2}}}) \hat i_z$$

but using gauss law we get a constant electric field $\vec E = \sigma/\pi \epsilon_0$

Where is the deviation here?

Comment: This question [has already been flagged as not suitable for this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/647873/electric-field-due-to-a-finite-plane-of-charge). You cannot just repost and hope noone notices. This is very disrespectful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an infinite plane.  Gauss' law still applies but is not useful in this case.  You cannot assume that the field is uniform. You have to integrate all the contributions from each area element. It is essential to understand the conditions for which a formula is valid.  The simple result you showed is valid for infinite plane which you don't have here.